# How can i drag and drop a 2d svg icon/object on the viewer and move it on the page as well @autodesk-forge @autodesk-viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

**drag and drop a 2d svg icon/object on the viewer and move it on the page as well**
i'm having a list of svg icons that i need to choose one and then drag it over to the viewer and also i can move it over the page using mouse moves

please help me with regards it any help is appericiated!

[requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSwOb.png)

Comment: Would the SVG content need to appear as part of the 3D model? e.g. perhaps you want to place it on the side of a wall? Or would it just behave like a markup that is always floating above a given object, always facing you?

Comment: yes i need it to be behave like a markup

Comment: Are you already using MarkupsCore to provide other kinds of markups or this is the only kind of markup you plan to provide, these drag and drop SVGs?
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/using-autodeskviewingmarkupscore-extension

Comment: i'm using MarkupsCore for drawing other things these are for other requirements i'm already using this link for loading svg but i need to make the svg draggable can you tell me or can you provide something how can i convert it to draggable svg